# When people talk about Princess Sapphire's male and female "hearts"... Is it possible it's supposed to be "souls"?

Tags: japanese-language, princess-knight

When people talk about Princess Sapphire's male and female "hearts"... Is it possible it's supposed to be "souls"?

Because it seems that memories are tied to her "hearts", given what I've heard about the effects when they're removed, changing her feelings on things, and perhaps her abilities too...

I'd think there should be at least another question on the site about how "hearts" and "souls" / "minds" are sorta mixed together in Japanese?

Perhaps this one, about the kanji... https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/where-exactly-in-your-body-is-%e5%bf%83

Answer (score 2, accepted):

心「こころ」(romaji: kokoro), according to [jisho](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%BF%83), means "mind; heart; spirit". So, it's not so much the physical heart as the methaphorical meaning.

The anatomical term is 心臓「しんぞう」(romaji: shinzou), for the record.

So I don't think it's really meant to be the physical heart but the conceptual "core of one's feelings and emotions" - sort of like when someone says someone is "heartless", it's not to mean that they literally lack the physical blood-pumping organ.